# union between requests with remplacement variables in sqlplus

Tags: sqlplus

I have 14 fields which are similar and I search the string 'A' on each of them.  I would like after that order by "position" field

```
-- some set in order to remove a lot of useless text
def col='col01'
select '&col' "Fieldname", 
       &col "value", 
       position
from oneTable
where &col like '%A%'
/
-- then for the second field, I only have to type two lines
def col='col02'
/
...
def col='col14'
/
```

Write all the fields which contains 'A'.  The problem is that those field are not ordered by position.

If I use UNION between table, I cannot take advantage of the substitution variables (&col), and I have to write a bash in unix in order to make the replacement back into ksh.  The problem is of course that database code have to be hard-coded in this script (connection is not easy stuff).

If I use a REFCURSOR with OPEN, I cannot group the results sets together.  I have only one request and cannot make an UNION of then. (print refcursor1 union refcursor2; print refcursor1+refcursor2 raise an exception, select * from refcursor1 union select * from refcursor2, does not work also).

How can concatenate results into one big "REFCURSOR"?  Or use a union between two distinct run ('/') of my request, something like holding the request while typing new definition of variables?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question ?

```
CREATE TABLE #containingAValueTable
(
    FieldName VARCHAR(10),
    FieldValue VARCHAR(1000),
    position   int
)
def col='col01'

INSERT INTO #containingAValueTable
(
FieldName , FieldValue, position
)
SELECT '&col' "Fieldname", 
       &col "value", 
       position
FROM yourTable
        WHERE &col LIKE '%A%'

/
-- then for the second field, I only have to type two lines
def col='col02'
INSERT INTO...
/

def col='col14'
/

select * from #containingAValueTable order by postion

DROP #containingAValueTable
```

But I'm not totally sure about your use of the 'substitution variable' called "col" (and i only have SQL Server to test my request so I used explicit field names)

edit : Sorry for the '#' charcater, we use it so often in SQL Server for temporaries, I didn't even know it was SQL Server specific (moreover I think it's mandatory in sql server for creating temporary table). Whatever, I'm happy I could be useful to you.

Comment: At this moment, I cannot understand why I have not thought of that yet...  I will check a few question about the final user's rights in data base (can we create table?). The only problem is that the table will be written on disk instead of being kept in memory but I do not think it will cause problem.

Comment: '#' is not accepted for beginning a name of table (SQL standard rule).  Only [a-zA-Z] are.